# How to pass id through form action in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I was trying to pass the `last inserted id` through form action in `Cakephp` when i click on a button.

I am a newbie in `Cakephp`. Here is the code i found out. Can you suggest the correct method tho get the last inserted is through `Form`?

```
<?php  echo $this->Html->link('View Quote', array('controller' => 'Stockcheck', 'action' => '../Quote/QuoteNo=Q1-1'), array('class' => 'button'));  ?>
```

QuoteNo=Q1-1 should be my last inserted id and QuoteNo is my field

Comment: get last inserted id like this $lastid = $this->Model->getLastInsertId(); and pass the id to action like  'action' => '../Quote/',$lastid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

---

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Quote', array('controller' => 'Stockcheck', 'action' => '../Quote/', $your_id));
```

---

for more help please read this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> ' . __('Delete') . '</span>', ['_name' => 'delete-administrator', $administrator->id], ['confirm' => "Are you sure you want to delete {$administrator->full_name}?", 'class' => 'btn btn-sm red', 'escape' => false, 'title' => 'Delete administrator details']); ?>

<?= $this->Form->postLink('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> ' . __('Delete') . '</span>', ['_name' => 'edit-administrator', $administrator->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-sm red', 'escape' => false, 'title' => 'Edit administrator details']); ?>
```

**- Using route name**